# File.Open not working under Windows 2008R2 IIS with Admin Credentials. Works under VS2010 Cassini

Tags: c#, wcf, file-io, iis-7.5, cassini

The following code works fine under Cassini, but not at all under IIS. I get `file not found`, and am unable to get files on a remote share, or locally when I tested C:\test.pdf (to test IIS permissions)

The intent of this application is to make a HTTP proxy that will allow files to be retrieved through a secure URL.  The security code has been omitted from this sample.  I'm just focusing on file access in this plain-vanilla sample.

I've made sure that the

1. Application pool (Process Model Identity) is running a Domain Admin account
2. Website Physical Path Credentials are running under the same admin account
3. The admin account has both `Batch` and `Run as a Service` rights in the local policy.

I access the WCF service using the following URL

`http://localhost:1651/services/GetFile.svc/get?swt=\\remoteserver\share\file.pdf`

```
[ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.NotAllowed)]
public interface IGetFile
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/get?swt={filename}", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    Stream Get(string filename); 
}


 [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class GetFile : IGetFile
{
    bool debug = true;

    public Stream Get(string filename )
    {
        //this will cause the file dialog to show the file name instead of "get" 
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add( "Content-disposition", string.Format("inline; filename={0}", filename));
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/octect-stream";

        FileStream fs1= null;

        //WindowsIdentity winId = new WindowsIdentity("aamankow@nfp.com");
        //using (winId.Impersonate())
        {
            try
            {
                fs1 = File.OpenRead(filename);
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e)
            {
                if (debug)
                throw;
                else
                return null;
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                if (debug)
                throw;
                else
                // message: Either a required impersonation level was not provided, or the provided impersonation level is invalid.
                return null;
            }
        }

        return fs1;
```

Comment: Does IIS have permissions to read the file?

Comment: Yes, it does (unless you think otherwise). I made the question more clear with the rights that IIS is running under.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code above doesn't work on version 3.5... just 4.0

Changing the app pool to 4.0 fixed the issue, and allowed me to read from any UNC

Answer (score 0):

Under your test system and cassini, you're running as your own user account, which has permissions to the root of the C:\ drive.  Under IIS, you're running under a special account which does not have permissions to the root of the C:\ drive.  It's poor practice to place files needed for your web site at this location.

Comment: I'm aware IIS uses different security.  I made my question more clear on how the development IIS server is using domain admin credentials.  In regards to the file on the root of C:\ that is just to show the problem may not be a remote permissions/connectivity issue.  I'm only testing file access..  I don't intend to go "production" with that at all,  I'm just trying to sort out the IIS issue at hand.